# Thread safety for cached objects in SQLAlchemy

Tags: multithreading, session, caching, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy and have a rookie question that hope someone can kindly help me out. I am developing a web application, and would like to be able to do the following three steps:

1. Create a SQLAlchemy `session` to do some querying, and save the results in cache
2. Use the cached object in cache without touching the database.
3. (Some time later, possibly in a different thread) Update one of the saved object in cache, and create another `session` to commit the change back to the database.

From my best understanding from the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_basics.html) (cited below), the object returned by one `session` should not be shared with another `session`.

> Making sure the Session is only used in a single concurrent thread at a time is called a “share nothing” approach to concurrency. But actually, not sharing the Session implies a more significant pattern; it means not just the Session object itself, but also all objects that are associated with that Session, must be kept within the scope of a single concurrent thread.

Therefore, I employed the following rather cumbersome approach to perform the steps above, but am wondering whether there is a easier and cleaner way of doing so. Thanks!

---

My current approach: define two data structures with the same fields, one to interact with SQLAlchemy, one to be saved in cache.

```
class DBItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item" 
    # Some fields.

class Item():
    # Same fields as DBItem.

# Step 1: query database and save to cache.
session = Session()
db_item = session.query(...).first()
item = copy_DBItem_to_Item(db_item)
cache.set("some-key", item)
session.close()

# Step 2: use the cached item
item = cache.get("some-key")
# use `item` in a read-only fashion

# Step 3: update the item in cache and in database.
item = cache.get("some-key")
session = Session()
db_item = session.query(...).first()
# Perform the same update to `item` and `db_item`.
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Comment: I don't think you can't do step 3. I've tried to solve quite a a similar problem a couple of weeks ago. Using your pseudocode example, once you close the session at the end of step 1., you can't update `item` anymore. It is not in the session you open in step 3. In my trials in a similar setting, I did add it directly, but I don't recall exactly the result; either I got an error message or the object just did not get updated. I think the latter; if you think it is interesting to know, I could run it again. Anyway, +1 for the question and I'll follow up to see if anybody has a better answer!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Irnzcig. Here is the way I see step 3 works: a new `session` is created, and then it performs a query to get the `db_item` associated with this new `session`. The `item` itself is a pure in-memory object that is not associated with any `session` or database.

Comment: Right. That's exactly my point, probably I did not explain it properly. If  `item` is just in memory, but you do nothing with the new session you've created in step 3, then even if you modify it no change is going to go through the database. But if you try to add `item` to the new session, you don't get any result either (in my test, I don't recall if I got an explicit error, else just no result). And I did not find a solution for it. Hope it is more clear now. Cheers.

Comment: @lrnzcig The database will be updated through the `session.commit()` statement. As is explained [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/cascades.html#save-update), when `db_item` is retrieved, the `session` keeps track of it, after `db_item` is updated, `session.commit()` will write through to the database. This is for updating an `item` only though. If adding a new `item`, a `session.add(db_item)` needs to be called before `session.commit()`.

Comment: I see... according to your link, the code that I tried should work. You know what, I will try to test it again this evening, and if it does work I will let you know. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ok. Indeed you are right. I tried again an it works! The solution I've implemented is a variation of this [SQLAlchemy recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject), but implementing a real cache. Thus, essentially the same kind of solution you describe. (I'd be happy to share my variation of the recipe, btw). I don't think there is a better way. Anyway I'll check if there are better answers to your question. Thanks again.